# Setting up a view to draw to in Objective-C (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, quartz-graphics

Okay, so, I'm all new to iPhone and stuff, but I'm not even at programming, I have many years of experience with ActionScript 2.0 and 3.0, I want to set up a view, that I can also pass variables to. The view is gonna draw everything with Quartz.

I tried to make another game where I tried to add a pointer to a NSMutableArray to the view class, but it didn't work cause I didn't know how to store an actual class.

I wanted to do like:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

but I had to do

```
[(View*)self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

didn't really work out in the end...

Okay, so now I got:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 viewClass = [[View class] retain];
 gameView = [[[viewClass alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero] retain];
 [gameView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is in my drawInContext:context, which is fired by drawRect:

Also, my drawRect does [self drawInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGMutablePathRef aPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(aPath, nil, 5, 5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(aPath, nil, 45, 43);
CGContextAddPath(context, aPath);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Nothing happens.

Help?

Oh yeah, I get this error: : invalid context
for each time I use those functions. :[

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using OpenGL for games because Quartz is so slow on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. Don't call `drawInContext` from `drawRect`. Instead just do this in your `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 5, 5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 45, 43);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

There's a couple things you  should note in that code. Whenever you do custom drawing in a UIView by overriding drawRect, use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` to get a reference to the current context. Second, when using `CGContext` there is no need to create a new `CGPath`. `CGContext` has the same drawing functions as `CGPath`, see the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html).

To create a view all you need to do is this:

```
gameView = [[YourView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Where `YourView` is your `UIView` subclass. You don't need to create a separate class reference (`viewClass`), and you don't need to call `retain` on the UIView object either, because the retain count is increased already when you create it. Also note that `CGRectZero` is a rectangle of size (0, 0). If you want your view to be visible then you need to supply an appropriately sized `CGRect` instead of `CGRectZero`.

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Ah, it works! Thanks!

And I also found out I had forgotten to do a specific thing in the XIB file haha. Such as saying the UIView is View. >______>

Well, thanks anyway!

Comment: @indragie .. i have custom UIView and in that view i want to fingure paint .. fingure paint is successfully done and now i want to try erase that ..but m getting context invalida .. please suggest me what can i do .. without drawRect() method can we draw in our custom UIView ?